# select all items inside a foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project were you select dates in a list, and than report x-amount of hours on a project on. It looks like this:
[image]

But what I want to is, I want to add a check-box after the months name if I want to select all dates under that month. But I am currently not sure how I would do that so I would be glad if I could get some guidance.

This is the view that prints out all the dates:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="portlet-body form">
    <div class="form-group">
        @if (ViewBag.MissingDays != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            var months = ((List<DateTime>)ViewBag.MissingDays).GroupBy(x => x.Month);
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, DateTime>> groups = months as IList<IGrouping<int, DateTime>> ?? months.ToList();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                i++;
                var month = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE").DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(group.Key);
                if (groups.Count() > 1)
                {
                    <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion1">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_@i">
                                        @month
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        @foreach (var date in group)
                                        {
                                            var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
                                            var day = date.ToString("ddd", new CultureInfo("sv-SE")).Substring(0, 2);
                                            <label style="padding-left: 10px">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />@day-@isoDate
                                            </label>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @foreach (var date in group)
                        {
                            var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
                            var day = date.ToString("ddd", new CultureInfo("sv-SE")).Substring(0, 2);
                            <label style="padding-left: 10px">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />@day-@isoDate
                            </label>
                        }
                    </div>
                }
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the script on how I select the dates right now.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="isoDate"]').change(function() {
        $("#date").val("");
        $('input[name="isoDate"]').each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {

                $("#date").val($("#date").val() + " " + $(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @ssilas777 I can use it for the project yes, I have already. Updated the question with the current script on how I select the dates. But I am not very good with it.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/42txfuru/2/

Comment: @ssilas777 a lot cleaner than what I tried to do. Post it as an answear and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this..

First remove the `id="isoDate"` as Id should be unique. And add a check box inside div near to `month` field

```
<input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" name="all" />
```

Now add a JQuery click handler

```
   $(".selectAll").on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('.panel-default').find("input[name='isoDate']").prop('checked',true);    
        } else {
          $(this).closest('.panel-default').find("input[name='isoDate']").prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
```

See working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/42txfuru/2/)

Answer (score 0):

first time use diferent ids for each input element. Then use js or jquery. Some like this :

```
var i = 0;
var ids = "juli_150505_" + i;
i++;
```

then you finde any checkbox element whot you want. By JS or jQuery.

Or you can use class param, then GetElementByClass().

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" class="Juli" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />
```

Comment: Doing that would give all the checkboxes the class juli

Comment: When you create a class for each month, then you can work with all the checkbox for that month. Select all after click on "month checkbox", check mont after select last checkbox in date list and many others

Answer (score 0):

Put a checkbox in front of every month name and give it a class name like 'chkAll'

```
$('input[name="chkAll"]').click(function(){ //if any chkAll is clicked
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() { 
           //Loop through
           $(this).prop('checked', true);
        });
    }
else 
 {
        $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
           $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }
});
```